# MVC: Where store JQuery/JS scripts and access it from View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have different script/JQuery-code inside `View-A` and `View-B`. Where are the proper place to store scripts, and then how do I let `View-A` access `Script-X` and `View-B` access `Script-Y`?

Comment: Load Script-X in View-A and Script-Y in View-B. It does not matter where they are stored, but convention is in the `/Scripts` folder

Comment: @StephenMuecke Okay, is this a proper way to add js-script in views`<script src="~/Scripts/Script-Y.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Yes (and of course you can use bundles)

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Muppen, I would suggest you make use of the `@section` declaration so you can place the scripts either in the head (discouraged) or before the end of the body tag (encouraged).